# MinValue for dx:ASPxSpinEdit doesn't works (asp.NET VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I try to create a form in which I added a dx:ASP:SpinEdit, which is a control able to control numeric data. I use it because I want the user only to put numeric value.

Here is the code I used to create it (graphically, not programmatically way) :

```
<form id="f_main" runat="server">

    <dx:ASPxSpinEdit ID="se_quantity" MinValue="1" runat="server"></dx:ASPxSpinEdit>

</form>
```

I would this element to block user from changing the value if it goes down 1. I am doing wrong with it ? Or should I use another control (I would in the best case keep this control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I didn't mentionned the type of my element, and the maxValue. I found a trick to overpass the fact that we should necessary put a MaxValue with a MinValue, and not only a MinValue. Here is how I did :

```
<dx:ASPxSpinEdit ID="spinEdit_1" MinValue="1" MaxValue="79228162514264337593543950335" NumberType="Integer" runat="server"></dx:ASPxSpinEdit>
```

The reason why I put a such long integer is that I needed the user to put a number from 1 to infinite (theorically). I searched for "Max value for MaxValue parameter for SpinEdit DevExpress" and I found this number by typing in my C# filethe following code :

```
Console.Write(spinEdit_1.MaxValue);
```

Then I found this number and put it in the "MaxValue" parameter. I should also precise the "NumberType" paramter for the user not to enter commas.

Hope it helps for similars problems.